# Recoding of data

Tags: r

I have looked through previous questions on recoding and cannot find answers to my question hence why i hope that someone can help me with my question.

The data below are expressed in degrees and show the different classes that aspect has been grouped into. I am trying to recode this variable so each "portion of the circle" is coded from 1-9. I can convert it if the starting point is from a single number but as in this case there is a range (e.g.0-22.5) involved i am a little puzzled

```
Aspect
0,22.5 (1)
22.5,67.5 (2)
67.5,112 (3)
112,158 (4)
158,202 (5)
202,248 (6)
248,292 (7)
292,338 (8)
338,360 (9)
```

Obviously as this is data based on aspect it is a continous scale from 0-360 (circle). Hoping someone can help

Comment: I think you're looking for `cut()` ...

Answer (score 1):

Just to add clarity to @BenBolker's comment above:

```
df = data.frame("original" = 1:360)
df$category = cut(df$original,
                  breaks = c(0, 22.5, 67.5, 112, 158, 202, 248, 292, 338, 360),
                  labels = 1:9)

summary(df$category)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying his comment, but once the break has been performed and each individual has been assigned to one of these categories how do i then recode so for example 0-22.5 =1 and 67.5-112=2. Hope you can help

Comment: Updated my code to include labeling; for more information use `?cut`

Comment: That would still be a factor though; to get to an integer apply `as.integer`.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that your class ranges look like they're slightly out by half a degree sometimes (maybe a rounding error).  I would have thought that every segment should be 45 degrees apart from the top 2.

E.g.

```
0,22.5 (1)
22.5,67.5 (2)
67.5,112.5 (3)
112.5,157.5 (4)
157.5,202.5 (5)
202.5,247.5 (6)
247.5,292.5 (7)
292.5,337.5 (8)
337.5,360 (9)
```

If you dont mind these new values and you are trying to obtain the class from the number of degrees, then you could do this.

1. Divide by 45
2. Add 1
3. Round to nearest whole number

E.g. 230 degrees

```
230 / 45 = 5.1111
5.1111 + 1 = 6.1111
round(6.111) = Class 6
```